# ruby on rails anonymize deleted record usernames

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model and a post model and I want that on an account deletion every user post gets anonymized. Currently I have dependent: destroy which destroys all records but instead I want them to have a anonymized username that leads to an empty page or sth so that I can still have those posts on my site.

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dependent: :nullify` instead of the `dependent: :destroy`

> :nullify causes the foreign key to be set to NULL. Callbacks are not executed.

Comment: Okay - I just tried that. It destroyed my user and kept the post. But the problem I have with this is that I now get errors. For example: NoMethodError at /posts/2
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass --> by <%= link_to @post.user.username, user_path(@post.user) %>
And I think I got a few of those references. How would I handle them?

Comment: If you code is toooo entangled, I would suggest adding deleted flag instead of deleting user

Comment: I could create a user named anonymized and replace the user_id of every post that got nullified with the user id of the anonymized user - am i correct? How would I do a on delete change function in rails?

Comment: @flenning12 Dont do that way. Set a couple of flags to true such as `deleted_user`, `anonymous_user` in the `destroy` method of the `users_controller` instead of deleting the object. And then filter those anonymous users along with their posts from the normal users's posts and perform whatever logic you want. This is the easiest way.

Comment: Got it working now.
Since I wanted to do this to still be able to use the posts afterwards I decided to go with my idea of creating a new user and just change the user id with a before_destroy method. I still decided to mark you question as the one that solved my issue. If someone wants the code from me just hit me up.

Answer (score 0):

One more option. Use `dependent: :nullify` instead of the `dependent: :destroy`, in this case after user deletion you have some posts without the user. So you just need to change a bit your views for these posts:

```
<% if @post.user %>
  <%= link_to @post.user.username, user_path(@post.user) %> 
<% else %>
  User was deleted # here goes any title/link you want for deleted users
<% end %>
```